# How can I design a Flow which is a average value of every latest 5 data of another Flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

There is a Flow which will emit data every 100ms, and I hope to get a average value of every latest 5 data of the Flow, and convert the average value as Double value into another Flow.

How can I design the Flow?

**Code A**

```
   fun soundDbFlow(period: Long = 100) = flow {
        while (true) {
            var data = getAmplitude()
            emit(data)
            delay(period)
        }
    }
    .get_Average_Per5_LatestData {...} //How can I do? or is there other way?
    .map { soundDb(it) }

    private fun getAmplitude(): Int {
        var result = 0
        mRecorder?.let {
            result = it.maxAmplitude
        }
        return result
    }    
        
    private fun soundDb(input:Int, referenceAmp: Double = 1.0): Double {
        return 20 * Math.log10(input / referenceAmp)
    }
```

**Added Content:**

To plplmax: Thanks!

I assume Code B will emit 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.....

Do you guarantee Code C will calculate `(1+2+3+4+5)/5` first, then calculate `(6+7+8+9+10)/5` second, ....  ? It's my expectation.

I worry that Code C maybe calculate `(1+2+3+4+5)/5` first, the calculate `(2+3+4+5+6)/5` sencond, ...

**Code B**

```
suspend fun soundDbFlow(period: Long) = flow {
    while (true) {
        val data = getAmplitude()
        emit(data)
        delay(period)
    }
}
```

**Code C**

```
private fun reduceFlow(period: Long = 100) = flow {
    while (true) {
        val result = soundDbFlow(period)
            .take(5)
            .map { soundDb((it / 5.0).roundToInt()) }
            .reduce { accumulator, value -> accumulator + value }
        emit(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a chunked operator like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a Flow that emits sequential [size]d chunks of data from the source flow, 
 * after transforming them with [transform].
 * 
 * The list passed to [transform] is transient and must not be cached.
 */
fun <T, R> Flow<T>.chunked(size: Int, transform: suspend (List<T>)-> R): Flow<R> = flow {
    val cache = ArrayList<T>(size)
    collect {
        cache.add(it)
        if (cache.size == size) {
            emit(transform(cache))
            cache.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
fun soundDbFlow(period: Long) = flow {
    while (true) {
        val data = getAmplitude()
        emit(data)
        delay(period)
    }
}
    .chunked(5) { (it.sum() / 5.0).roundToInt() }
    .map { soundDb(it) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need add `suspend` before  `fun soundDbFlow` in your code ?

Comment: If it is blocking, you should make it a suspend function that wraps its blocking code in `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` so it won’t be blocking.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I should to add `flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` for long time operation, and `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` maybe cuase error, right?

Comment: Sorry, I missed seeing your comment before. If `soundDbFlow` is a proper suspend function (doesn't block), `flowOn` shouldn't be necessary, but it doesn't hurt. Might as well take everything off the main dispatcher, even the minor calculations that aren't really blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
var result = 0

fun soundDbFlow(period: Long) = flow {
    while (true) {
        delay(period)
        val data = getAmplitude()
        emit(data)
    }
}

fun reduceFlow(period: Long = 100) = flow {
    while (true) {
        val sum = soundDbFlow(period)
            .take(5)
            .reduce { accumulator, value -> accumulator + value }

        val average = (sum / 5.0).roundToInt()
        emit(soundDb(average))
    }
}

fun getAmplitude(): Int {
    return ++result
}

fun soundDb(input: Int, referenceAmp: Double = 1.0): Double {
    return 20 * log10(input / referenceAmp)
}

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    reduceFlow().collect { println(it) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you guarantee `reduceFlow`  always take latest 5 data and no repetition data are taken?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW, I fixed reduceFlow to avoid -infinity at low values. What about `(1+2+3+4+5)/5 first, then calculate (6+7+8+9+10)/5 secondly`, I have checked now, and this guarantees correct execution (if my hands are all right :D)

Comment: I think the problem here is after every 5 emissions of the source flow, it will immediately start a new copy of the source flow, so there won't be a `period`-sized interval before the first value of each chunk of 5. I also wouldn't recommend rounding the divisions by 5.0 to an Int before adding them together because of the extreme loss of precision. If you had a flow of [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], this would give an average of 5, and if you had a flow of [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], this would give an average of 0.

Comment: @Tenfour04, thanks for the comment, you're right :)
I fixed the issue with precision and delay (however, this is not the best solution with a delay, because the first delay can be crucial for the author)